# How to always show the page browser in tt_news?

Tags: php, plugins, typo3, typoscript

Is there a way to always show the page browser, regardless of the set limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No built-in switch for this I suppose. Maybe you can place a generic marker to your template which is always replaced with a browsebox:

In the template:

```
<div class="pagebrowser>###MYPAGEBROWSER###</div>
```

In tt_news setup:

```
plugin.tt_news {
     genericmarkers {
         MYPAGEBROWSER < plugin.tt_news.pageBrowser
         MYPAGEBROWSER {
               (some config goes here) 
         }
     }
}
```